# TypeError: search.valueChanges.debounceTime is not a function

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, angular2-forms

I am just learning angular2. At the time of applying something at input changes, I am getting the error.

app.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    form: ControlGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = fb.group({
            search: []
        });

        var search = this.form.find('search');
        search.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400)
            .map(str => (<string>str).replace(' ','‐'))
            .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    };

 }
```

Error:

[image]

How to solve this? Am I missing something?

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQIQvFYAvsPv9Pu8xZap?p=preview)

**N.B.** I cannot produce anything at plunker as I am writing angular2 first time at plunker now. I have written only my app.ts code at plunker. I have showed the screenshot of error from my local pc. I will be grateful too if you tell me the way of running angular2 project at plunker.

Comment: actually you are mixing imports of angular2 at your plunker see here is working demo of angular2 plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/XNvJChxONhZpY04Iruf6?p=preview

Comment: sorry, still I am not sure how to write it at plunker. I have followed clicking: new>Angular Js>2.0.X(TS). Then, I have replaced code of app.ts with my app.ts. What else need I do to? replace all the file's code like app.js, index.html etc with mine?

Comment: Yeah according to your need you have to change the index.html as well, but better is if you fork someone else's plunker for writing your code, because I takes more time to write your own code

Answer (score 100, accepted):

you  Just need to import these to remove your error. You are getting runtime error because Observables by default come with just a few operators. You have to explicitly import them like this -

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

<kbd>[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8PIkY2OQ3ZO8mmZNKNNP?p=preview)</kbd>

## Update

Angular 6 onwards, debounceTime is imported as following -

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

other imports you can import from this path are -

- switchMap
- tap
- map
- distinctUntilChanged

etc..

Comment: I am importing it using `import {debounceTime} from "rxjs/operator/debounceTime"` which does not work.

Comment: Looks like there's a difference between the two files, mine autocompleted to that as well. Ensure you've removed any existing imports and replace it with what pardeep has. Then make sure your valueChanges to the way described in the OP, double check your template to make sure you aren't mapping changes there and it should work.

Comment: You need to import debounceTime() like this for angular 6 import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Didn't work for me. But fixed by adding a pipe
`.pipe(debounceTime(400))` and importing `import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: @Adrian thanks for pointing out, I have updated the answer.
earlier answer was written before release of angular v6.

Answer (score 14):

Put debounceTime(400) inside a pipe() function.

example

```
var search = this.form.find('search');
    search.valueChanges
        .pipe(debounceTime(400))
        .map(str => (<string>str).replace(' ','‐'))
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

add imports for each operator

```js
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and then use pipes to pass all the RxJS operators

```js
    this.searchTextInput.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .subscribe((term): void => {
        console.log({ term });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
```